How to idiomatically return an accumulated slice/array from a Zig function
See the following code
const std = @import("std");
const print = std.debug.print;

test "Demo accumulation" {
    const accumulated = try accumulate();
    print("DEBUG - accumulated values are {any}\n", .{accumulated});
}

fn accumulate() ![]u32 {
    var gpa = std.heap.GeneralPurposeAllocator(.{}){};
    defer _ = gpa.deinit();
    const allocator = gpa.allocator();

    var list = std.ArrayList(u32).init(allocator);
    // defer list.deinit(); <-- this is the problem line
    try list.append(1);
    try list.append(2);
    try list.append(3);
    return list.items;
}

If the problem-line is commented-out, the compiler (correctly) warns me of a memory leak; but if it's kept in, then referencing accumulated gives a segmentation fault. Is it possible in Zig to avoid either bad consequence while continuing to return a []u32 (as opposed to, say, returning the ArrayList and deinit()ing it in the context of the calling function?)
In particular, the following still gives a memory leak:
...
    var list = std.ArrayList(u32).init(allocator);
    defer list.deinit();
    try list.append(1);
    try list.append(2);
    try list.append(3);

    const response = try allocator.alloc(u32, list.items.len);
    @memcpy(response, list.items);
    return response;
...


https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/std/#std.array_list.ArrayListAligned.toOwnedSlice

Or just return the ArrayList.

You create and destroy an allocator in the same function that is supposed to return a slice...

"Or just return the ArrayList" - yes, that was what I was referring to in "as opposed to, say, returning the ArrayList...". I know that would work - but I was trying to find out how to make this work.

Idiomatically, the function would take an allocator. It can return a slice or the ArrayList itself, depending on the need.
test "Demo accumulation" {
    const allocator = std.testing.allocator;
    const accumulated = try accumulate(allocator);
    defer allocator.free(accumulated);
    print("DEBUG - accumulated values are {any}\n", .{accumulated});
}

fn accumulate(allocator: std.mem.Allocator) ![]u32 {
    var list = std.ArrayList(u32).init(allocator);
    errdefer list.deinit();
    try list.append(1);
    try list.append(2);
    try list.append(3);
    return list.toOwnedSlice();
}

This prints:
$ zig build test
test
└─ run test stderr
DEBUG - accumulated values are { 1, 2, 3 }

